# Hover over Text show image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i want to hover over "durchwahl" and make it popup a profile image on my mouse.
However, on the bottom of my page the images moves out of the visible area.
Is their a way i can fix it? and i really want to do it with css instead of jquery!
i am currently using jquery to popup an image @my mouse position:

http://jsfiddle.net/rrcef6bn/

functions.php:

```
$value = $value . "<a  href='images/".getPictureName($nutzer['vorname'],$nutzer['nachname']).".jpg' class='preview'> <img   class='img' src='images/phone.jpg' border='0' width='12' height='12'>".$nutzer['durchwahl'];
```

Comment: paste in http://jsfiddle.net/ , and come back please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rrcef6bn/